# Vector dot product in machine learning

Tags: vectors, inner-products

In machine learning, I often see equations like $y = w^{T} x+b$ and $y = w^{T} \cdot x+b$, but which one is correct?

According to this [dot product](http://math.stanford.edu/%7Ejmadnick/R3.pdf) that says "Let $v, w \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then $v^{T}w = v \cdot w$", I think $y = w^{T} x+b$ is incorrect because it is equivalent to $y = w \cdot x+b$. Because the dimension of $w$ and $x$ were originally the same, the dot product can't be done.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: I really don't understand your question. They are both equally correct as far as finite dimensional vector spaces are concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are competing conventions at play here. In the mathematical community, it is primarily as you describe it: the "dot-product" is an operation between two vectors of the same shape. This convention is demonstrated, for instance, in the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product)

On the other hand, the computer science community will use the term "dot-product" to refer to the usual [product of two matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication). This convention is demonstrated, for instance, in the documentation for the [numpy dot function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).